# Viewing relationship classes ties for multiple features

Tags: arcgis-9.3, relationship-class

I've been working with a complex ArcGIS 9.3.1 geodatabase with multiple feature classes (FC's) interconnected by many relationship classes.

My question: supposing I have a FC with features a,b,c and another FC with features 1,2,3 - **I want to see which featuers of the first FC are to connected to which  features of the second FC** (of course in reality, the geodatabase is much more complex with more FC's, more features and more relations).

Now, I know that the **IDENTIFY** tool does it, but it does it to one feature at a time, and I can't export the ties to an outer file (it is only visual). Is there any tool I can use to do that for whole layers at a time?

(I've seen Geodatabase Diagrammer very briefly, but as far as I understood, it is useful for the planning of the structure of the geodatabase, but not it's content. correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: If you trace through these relationships, do you ever encounter loops?

Comment: the arcgis identify tool actually lets you go through a endless loop, if you insist with it (as for my GDB, it happens as well, but it's rare).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to open the Attribute Table. Once the table is open you can select any number of features. Once Selected, click the Options Button and view Related Tables. This will create a fly-out list of the related tables either via GDB Relations Classes or ArcMap Relates, select the table you want and it's table will then open with the related selection. In the child table you can then do the same.

This will consume screen real estate but should allow you to have the kinds of visibility you require.

Have a great day,

CDB

Comment: 1. OK, the weird thing is that sometimes the child table opens with the selection, and sometimes it opens without the selection (when in all times there is a valid selection in the parent table.

Comment: 2. The second issue is that this method enables me only to check one feature at a time (like the identify), and not whole feature classes as I need (my FC hold thousands of features). I wonder if it's possible to make a python script that will do that (but unfortunatly I haven't the knowledge to do that).

Comment: @jonatr RE comment #1: our users experience this as well in ArcMap  9.3.1 to a 9.3.1 geodatabase.  Either missed selections or *wrong* selections.  It was intermittent.   I tested in ArcObjects using IRelationshipClass2.GetObjectsRelatedToObjectSet and received 100% correct results.  As a result, we don't use ArcMap with relationship classes for anything important.  We don't experience the issue in ArcMap 10.

Comment: Jay, so you use it only through arcobjects? Thanks for the tip, at least I know there's a way around...

Comment: There is another way for you to view all connections at once, you can write a report using the ArcMap Report Writer, as this will then enable you to add what ever connections you wish, the downside will be speed and a lack of on the fly verification. The statement that Jay said on 9.3.1 is generally acknowledged to be either a memory addressing issue which was reportedly fixed at 9.3.1 SP1 or a primary key error. But as most of these issues I have come across have been to do with memory 10 would be my suggestion as 10 makes better use of the GPU so the CPU and RAM can be doing other work